# Sublime 3: Is there a way to remove tabs/spaces from empty lines?

Tags: editor, sublimetext3

I am looking for a way to force Sublime 3 to remove all spaces and tabs from any indented line that is empty in my code, either when I save the file or as I am typing.

Is there a way?

```
|
if (...) {
    |
    some code
    |
}
```

to

```
|
if (...) {
|
    some code
|
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add this to your preferences ([Preferences > Settings](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/settings.html)):

```
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": true
```

This will remove whitespaces from the end of all lines, even empty ones, when you save the file.

Quoting the default settings file:

```
// Set to true to removing trailing white space on save
"trim_trailing_white_space_on_save": false,
```

Comment: This is so nice- especially after using the sublime package AutoDocstring to generate Python docstrings, because they automatically add spaces to empty lines between the docstrings, and my linting fails on those lines!